# Datepicker set date during page load

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker but it doesn't show date in the input when page is first time loaded. The date is set only after click.

```
$('#starts-on').datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy' ,
        }).datepicker( "option", { setDate:"0",
                maxDate:'+3y -1d',
                minDate:'0' } );
```

How can the date be loaded during first time page loading? Moreover, i want to disable the text box to add text. Any help?

Comment: can you post a fiddle showing the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate), like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#starts-on').datepicker("setDate", your_Date_here);
});
```

Added:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#starts-on').datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy' ,
        }).datepicker( "option", { setDate:"0",
                maxDate:'+3y -1d',
                minDate:'0' } );
    $('#starts-on').datepicker("setDate", "0"); //"0" for current date
});
```

Comment: How do you set other parameter like minDate, maxDate?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the initialization object literal all in the first call of `datepicker`:

```
$( "#starts-on" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy' ,
    setDate:"0",
    maxDate:'+3y -1d',
    minDate:'0'
});
```

Setting an option for `datepicker` after initialization has a different syntax (see the example for `dateformat` [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)).

Answer (score 0):

u can try

```
$("selector").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"}).datepicker("setDate", "0");
```